# Prevent Slider from click event on Desktop

Tags: javascript, swipe, addeventlistener, dom-events

I have build a slideshow with the very leightweight Carousel [siema.js](https://pawelgrzybek.com/siema/) and wanted to link each element (slides) with a Javascript EventListener afterwards.

```
  clickArea[i].addEventListener('click',openclicktag,false);
```

When I add the links with the event "click" I can't use the slider correctly anymore on desktop, because on each swipe it opens the link. Is there another javascript event that would solve this? Or how could I avoid this behaviour on desktop?

(on mobile it works fine, but I want it to work on desktop as well)

I've build an example on codepen to show my problem: https://codepen.io/behringbob/pen/ayrJzR

Because everything needs to be as small as possible I would appreciate a solution without jquery.

---

PS: I want to thank the stack overflow community for helping me so much in the past. Its a great resource for coding knowledge :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227527/how-to-prevent-swipe-to-trigger-click) SO question.

Comment: I don't want to use jquery, because it needs to be as leightweight as possible.